# Querying fields from nested Arrays/Structs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have just started working with JSON data and have the following schema to work with:

```
root
 |-- parameters: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to query the data using but getting an error stating that no Struct Field is present for Parameters:

```
df.select("parameters[0].name").show()
```

Error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'No such struct field parameters[0]
```

Can someone please let me know what is the simplest way of querying this nested data without any transformations?

Comment: It is always a good practice to provide impute and output data in a tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select(F.posexplode("parameters").alias("position","parameters")).where('position = 0').select('parameters.name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have dataframe with ArrayType as one of the column type

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_b = spark.createDataFrame([('1',['10', '20'])],[ "ID","TYPE"])
+---+--------+
| ID|    TYPE|
+---+--------+
|  1|[10, 20]|
+---+--------+
```

Then you if you are trying to extract the data from the Array column, you can use - **getItem()** as below

```
df_b = df_b.withColumn('type_col_1', F.col('TYPE').getItem(0))
df_b = df_b.withColumn('type_col_2', F.col('TYPE').getItem(1))
df_b.show()
+---+--------+----------+----------+
| ID|    TYPE|type_col_1|type_col_2|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
|  1|[10, 20]|        10|        20|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
```